# Integration Sub Heading Disappeared

Tags: facebook, integration

I was trying to create the iframe settings for my new facebook fan page and stupidly clicked and closed the developers.facebook.com site and when i logged back in, the Integration sub heading section had disappeared so I couldn't fill in the website details. 
I tried to set up a new app within it but the Integreation Sub Heading section is not visible there either. What am I doing wrong?
Thanks,
Annette Young

Answer (score 0):

From the summary settings of your app `https://developers.facebook.com/apps/{your app id}/summary` you should see "App on Facebook" section near the bottom.  Click the check mark beside it and it will open the input boxes to enter your Canvas URLs (iFrame app).